# MEF over Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

We are just doing some research for some technical decisions,
and I am not really pleased with the sources I found so far and
do not have the time to work myself so deep to do a thorough
proof of concept, as we are still in the 'pre-PoC' phase.

So my question is: Is it possible to use the Managed Extensibilty Framework(MEF), including dynamic loading of libraries, in code transformed from C# to Android.Xamarin? 
I found out that it should not work on Xamarin.iOs because of the AoT compiling, which makes sense to me.

Thanks a lot for any effort,

Markus

Comment: I think this is not the right place to ask. Moreover, if you are not please with the sources you found,  I am not sure that a random internet stranger is better.

Comment: Why is this not the right place (serious question)?
AND
I have not found anything at all about this and we just want to know if it's even worth starting with it.
Maybe I'll update the question...

Comment: @mindfxxxedCoder hi did you found out any answers? we are doing the same thing.

Comment: nope, and we gave up on it to be honest, without any proof of concept